# Tem como identificar repetição da mesma letra com regex em python?

Tags: python, regex

Quero pegar repetição de letras mais de duas vezes. Exemplo: **prrrograaaaamaaçãoo**. Transformaria essa string em **prrograamaaçãoo** usando uma lógica com regex.
Tentei `/[a-zA-Z]{3,}/gi`, mas pega qualquer sequência de letras e não a mesma.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Apesar de não serem em Python, as perguntas indicadas acima mostram o caso mais geral, bastando adaptar pro seu caso. Basicamente, coloque a regex que corresponde à letra entre parênteses, depois use `\1` para se referir a mesma letra, e ajuste  quantidade de acordo com o que você quer